# Creating a functional window using C++, Open GL and GLFW

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I've been trying to make a simple game in opengl using the GLFW library, but I've gotten stuck on a few parts due to changes in the GLFW. Had a few problems due to the changes in the library, but the change log helped out a bit. My problem is that I can't close my window properly using "glfwGetWindowAttrib" and I have no idea what to variable to add since I've seen no replacement for "GLFW_OPENED".

```
    //Include GLFW
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)

{
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_TRUE);
    glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Test Game", NULL, NULL);

    bool running = true;

    while (running) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers;

//      running = glfwGetWindowAttrib();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [glfw documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/window.html#window_close), you have to use the `glfwWindowShouldClose` method:

```
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    //Do what you need

    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    glfwPollEvents();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it didn't help, I just got more errors.